# Where can I get my BrainTree Client Token?

Tags: android, parse-platform, braintree

I am implementing BrainTree API into my app for credit card transactions. This function requires me to provide a Client Token:

```
public void onBraintreeSubmit(View v) {

    DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest()
            .clientToken(CLIENT_TOKEN);
    startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(this), 0);
}
```

I am using Parse-Server. What exactly is my Client Token?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

From the Braintree docs:

> A client token is a signed data blob that includes configuration and
>   authorization information required by the [Braintree client SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client). These
>   should not be reused; a new client token should be generated for each
>   request that's sent to Braintree. For security, we will revoke client
>   tokens if they are reused excessively within a short time period. <sup>[1](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/client-token)</sup>

Your [server](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server) is responsible for [generating the client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/#generate-a-client-token). Here's a Node.js example [from the Braintree docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/node#send-a-client-token-to-your-client):

```
app.get("/client_token", function (req, res) {
  gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    res.send(response.clientToken);
  });
});
```